# Оптимизация кода в рамках задачи «Делители»

Tags: python, алгоритм, теория-чисел

Всем здравствуйте! Есть код для решения задачи, но он работает слишком медленно. Нужно уложится в 1 секунду, а программа работает на ~1.1 секунду. Возможно, нужно как-то по-другому решить задачу, но не понимаю, как. Помогите, пожалуйста.

**Условие задачи:**
Дано натуральное число . Подсчитайте количество таких пар чисел ( и ), что:  и  — делители ;  `<` ;  и  — взаимно простые;  `≤` .

**Выходные данные:**
Вводится натуральное число  `≤ 10**8`.

**Выходные данные:**
Выведите количество таких пар.

**Код:**

```
from math import gcd

def full_factorization(n):
    p = []
    d = 2
    while d * d <= n:
        while n % d == 0:
            p.append(d)
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
        p.append(n)
    return p


def dividers(n):
    p = full_factorization(n)
    divs = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n%i == 0:
            divs.append(i)
    return divs

def main(n):
    used = []
    number = 0
    div = dividers(n)
    for a in div:
        for b in div:
            if a < b and (a,b) not in used and gcd(a,b) == 1 and a*b <= n:
                number += 1
            used += [(a, b), (b, a)]
    return number
n = int(input())
print(main(int(input())))
```

Comment: Перебор - это не наш метод.

Разложите заданное `n` на простые множители. Дальше работайте только с количествами каждого отдельного делителя. С учётом того, что раз `a` и `b` взаимно просты, то наличие какого-то количества какого-то множителя у одного из чисел автоматом определяет нулевое их количество у другого.

Comment: Здравствуйте, @Akina, мне не совсем понятно, как именно нужно организовать новый оптимизированный алгоритм. Я обновил код в вопросе, добавив в него функцию разложения на простые множители. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Допустим, разложение включает два в кубе. Тогда либо a имеет среди делителей 0 двоек, а b соответственно от 0 до 3 штук, либо наоборот. Поскольку простые множители взаимно просты, каждый перебирается независимо, т.е. количества вариантов тупо перемножаем. И отбрасываем тривиальное, когда хотя бы один равен единице.

Comment: Не программа работает 1.1 секунды, а через 1.1 секунды её прерывают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Замечание по вашему коду:**

```
def dividers(n):
    p = full_factorization(n) # 'p' нигде не используется
    divs = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n%i == 0:
            divs.append(i)
    return divs
```

**Моё решение:**

Для нахождения множителей числа можно применить более быстрый алгоритм, видео с объяснением на английском - [Finding factors of a number](https://youtu.be/vcn2ruTOwFo).

```
from math import gcd

def solve(num):
    factors = []
    a = 1
    b = num
    while a < b:
        b = num // a
        if b * a == num:
            factors.append(a)
            # Обработка случая равных множителей, например 'a' = 10 и 'b' 10,
            # при num = 100.
            if a != b:
                factors.append(b)
        a += 1

    factors.sort()
    # Для наглядности
    print("factors", factors, '\n')

    cnt = 0
    # Проверяем все комбинации множителей.
    for i, a in enumerate(factors, 1):
        # Так как список factors отсортирован и состоит из уникальных значений,
        # любое число, находящееся правее текущего, будет больше, 
        # что даёт нам выполнение условия 'a < b'.
        for b in factors[i:]:
            # Если встретилось 'b', которое при умножении на 'a'
            # даёт произведение больше, чем 'num', то текущий цикл
            # можно завершать, так как дальше 'b' будет только увеличиваться.
            if a * b > num:
                break

            if gcd(a, b) == 1:
                # Для наглядности
                print("pair\t", a, b)
                cnt += 1

    return cnt

inpt = 100
print("\nanswer", solve(inpt))
```

**Output**

```
factors [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100] 

pair     1 2
pair     1 4
pair     1 5
pair     1 10
pair     1 20
pair     1 25
pair     1 50
pair     1 100
pair     2 5
pair     2 25
pair     4 5
pair     4 25

answer 12
```

Comment: Замечательное, простое и быстрое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не укладываетесь по времени из-за медленной функции `dividers`. Она перебирает *n* чисел чтобы выделить из них делители *n*. Её можно ускорить, если правильно воспользоваться разложением из `full_factorization`. Всё остальное работает достаточно быстро потому что делителей мало: любое число *n ≤ 10<sup>8</sup>* имеет не более *768* делителей. Но я хочу предложить другой путь, который совмещает производительность *O(√n)* с относительной простотой кода - не нужно строить все делители чтобы найти ответ.

Обозначим искомое число пар множителей за *f(n)*. Из набора условий ограничивающих пары для *f* уберём требование *a < b* и обозначим новое количество пар множителей через *g(n)*. Заметим что каждая пара *(a, b)* для *f* соответствует двум парам для *g*, а именно парам *(a, b)* и *(b, a)*. Также в *g* входит одна особенная пара - *(1, 1)*, которой нет соответствия среди пар *f*. Это неформальное рассуждение приводит к формуле *2f(n) + 1 = g(n)*.

Дальше будем заниматься вычислением *g(n)*.

Пусть *n<sub>1</sub>* и *n<sub>2</sub>* взаимно простые. Покажем что *g(n<sub>1</sub>)g(n<sub>2</sub>) = g(n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>2</sub>)*.

Пусть *(a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>)* - пара множителей для числа n<sub>1</sub>, а *(a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>)* - пара множителей для числа n<sub>2</sub>. Рассмотрим пару *(a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>)*. Множители в ней взаимно просты, следовательно эта пара входит в *g(n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>2</sub>)*.

Обратно. Возьмём любую пару *(a, b)* из *g(n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>2</sub>)*. *a* разлагается в произведение *a = a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>*, где *n<sub>1</sub> : a<sub>1</sub>*, *n<sub>2</sub> : a<sub>2</sub>*. Разложение существует и единственно, так как *n<sub>1</sub>* и *n<sub>2</sub>* взаимно простые. Разложим аналогично *b*: *b = b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>*, где *n<sub>1</sub> : b<sub>1</sub>*, *n<sub>2</sub> : b<sub>2</sub>*. Пара *(a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>)* соответствует *g(n<sub>1</sub>)*, пара *(a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>)* соответствует *g(n<sub>2</sub>)*.

Так как отображение *((a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>), (a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>)) ↔ (a, b)* взаимнооднозначное, мощности множеств слева и справа равны. Слева произведение *g(n<sub>1</sub>)g(n<sub>2</sub>)*, справа *g(n)*. Равенство доказано.

Это свойство *g* называется [мультипликативностью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Мультипликативные функции можно вычислять по разложению числа на простые. Заметим что если *p* - простое, то *g(p<sup>a</sup>) = 2a + 1*. Проверяется перечислением всех возможных пар. Тогда общая формула для разложения на простые будет:

*g(∏p<sub>i</sub><sup>a<sub>i</sub></sup>) = ∏(2a<sub>i</sub> + 1)*, где *p<sub>i</sub>* - различные простые.

С теорией покончили. Практика: по разложению *n* на простые вычислить *g(n)*, затем восстановить *f(n) = (g(n) - 1)/2*.

Функция `g` основана на общем алгоритме факторизации числа: сперва из числа удаляется степень двойки, затем проверяется делимость на нечётные числа. Если делится, соответствующий делитель оказывается простым и мы его тоже удаляем из числа. Цикл делает не более *(√n)/2* итераций.

```
import math


def g(n):

    def factor(n, g, p):
        f = 1
        while n % p == 0:
            n //= p
            f += 2
        return n, g * f

    n, g = factor(n, 1, 2)
    i = 3
    n_sqrt = math.isqrt(n)
    while i <= n_sqrt:
        if n % i == 0:
            n, g = factor(n, g, i)
            n_sqrt = math.isqrt(n)
        i += 2
    if n > 1:
        n, g = factor(n, g, n)
    return g


def f(n):
    return (g(n) - 1) // 2


print(f(int(input())))
```

Работает для *n ≤ 10<sup>8</sup>* мгновенно. Цикл в функции `g` выполняется не более *5000* раз.

> ```
> $ echo 9699690 | python f.py
> 3280
>
> $ echo 67108864 | python f.py
> 26
>
> $ echo 99999989 | python f.py
> 1
>
> $ echo 91891800 | python f.py
> 9922
> ```