# Задача на делители числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Дано натуральное число n. Подсчитайте количество таких пар чисел (a;b), что:

1.a и b — делители n;

2.a < b

3.a и b — взаимно простые;

4.ab≤n.

Ограничения: n < 108

Входные данные - n

Выходные данные - количество пар (a, b)

```
     def gcd(a, b):
       if b <= 0:
           return a
       if a > b:
           a, b = b, a  
       return gcd(a, b - a) == 1
    def dividers(n):
       divs = []
       for i in range(1, n + 1):
           if n % i == 0:
               divs.append(i)
       return divs
    def main(n):
       used = []
       number = 0
       div = dividers(n)
       for a in div:
           for b in div:
               if a != b:  
                   if (a, b) not in used:              
                       if gcd(a, b):
                           if a * b <= n:
                               number += 1
               used += [(a, b), (b, a)]
       return number

print(main(int(input())))
```

Comment: "Программа выдает неверный ответ" . Мне нужна помощь, так как этот код неверный

Comment: Посмотрите https://oeis.org/A173675

Comment: Получите разложение в виде 2^p*3^q*5^r*7^s..., а дальше сами думайте.

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста, кодом.

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139661/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8

Comment: Да, спасибо большое. Я уже разобралась)